# Reading output parameter without closing the datareader

Tags: ado.net

I am not sure if this is even possible but just needed a solution to my current issue.
I have a method in Data layer which returns SqlDataReader object. this is called by Business layer later.

```
public SqlDataReader GetAll(out int count)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    IDataReader reader = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sproc", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // add parameters
    SqlParameter outputParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Count", SqlDbType.Int);
    outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    conn.Open();

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            //read in data
        }
        **// not possible as the reader is not closed.
        // need to set this out variable here
        count = outputParam.Value; //doesn't work/**

    }

}
return reader;
}
```

please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: Is that code you have? You have finished reading the results (unless you have multiple result sets returned by the stored procedure) why not just close the reader and obtain the OUT parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this piece of code :

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("testproc", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var countParam = command.CreateParameter();
            countParam.ParameterName = "@TotalCount";
            countParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            countParam.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            command.Parameters.Add(countParam);


            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.Write("exec");
                }

                totalCount = (int)countParam.Value; //totalCount has valid value 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I know my code is not good by design itself. but that's what i had to work on. @SergeyG : i think our codes are almost similar. Does it work for you?