# Call a sql server stored procedure when submit button is clicked In asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, submit-button

I have following code and now I want to call a stored procedure of SQL, when submit button is clicked.

Can anyone help me where I should place the code that calls a SP when submit button is clicked?

Default.aspx

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<table align="center">

<strong>Login Form</strong>

<tr>
<td>
Username:
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUser" ErrorMessage="Please enter Username" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" runat="server" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password:
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPWD" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPWD" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPWD" ErrorMessage="Please enter Password"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Log_Users where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPWD.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username Or Password')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Details.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Details.aspx.cs" Inherits="Details" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="lblDisplay" runat="server" Text="Welcome to our sample Site" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Details.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class Details : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a stored procedure with your select statement:

```
select * from Log_Users where UserName =@username and Password=@password
```

and alter your ADO.net code to consume this Stored procedure as,

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your sp name", con);

 cmd.CommandTpe = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: I already have a Sp
create Proc USerLogin
 (Username VarChar(50),  UPassword varChar(50), OutRes int OUTPUT
 )
 AS
set OutRes = (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Log_Users 
WHERE Username = Username And [Password] = UPassword)
if(OutRes = 1)

begin
set OutRes = 1--Login is Correct
end
else
begin
set OutRes = 0  --Bad login
end

Comment: Hey, you have already used the sp with out parameters, then whats the issue you are facing with: Check the value present in the outparameter or store the outparameter value in a string/int time being and write: Eg: int redirect(assign the value of the OUT parameter to this); if(redirect){ Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");} else{ Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx");}

Comment: I think you are not getting the output parameter value from the stored procedure... just see this link which describes how an output parameter is declared and used with datareader.. hope this helps.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432900/reading-output-parameter-without-closing-the-datareader

Comment: can u suggest me how to create a SP with parameters. because i want pass parameters when button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedure based command text instead of using normal command text;
    Firstly create a storedproedure with out parameter(as well as in parameters): In Parameters are to check the username and password against the table and Out Parameter is to return whether user is a valid one or not after checking against the database.

So, make use of

```
cmd.CommandText="StoredProcedureName";
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

And Use out and in parameters; And after getting the out parameter value, you can redirect to the details/error page according to the credentials provided by the user.. :)

Comment: or you can specify command text directly in sqlcommand object like: new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName",con);

Comment: I already have a Sp create Proc USerLogin (Username VarChar(50), UPassword varChar(50), OutRes int OUTPUT ) AS set OutRes = (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Log_Users WHERE Username = Username And [Password] = UPassword) if(OutRes = 1) begin set OutRes = 1--Login is Correct end else begin set OutRes = 0 --Bad login end –

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the query that you are passing to command object in the below  line-Pass the stored procedure name. It should be in the Button click event. You have written teh code at the right place.

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", con);

   cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for the stored procedure.. below is the one with OUTPUT parameter ..

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'proc_name')
BEGIN
DROP Procedure [dbo].[proc_name]
END

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


/*
File Name : proc_name.sql
Description : 
Author : Vinay.T
Date :
*/

CREATE Procedure [dbo].[proc_name]
(
     @Username VarChar(50)
    ,@UPassword varChar(50)
    ,@OutRes int OUTPUT 
)
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(510) --
        ,@ErrorSeverity INT --16 if business error
BEGIN

SET @OutRes = (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].Log_Users WHERE Username = @Username And [Password] = @UPassword)


END
GOTO SUCCESS

SUCCESS:
RETURN 1
CRASH:
RAISERROR (@ErrMsg, @ErrorSeverity, 1) WITH NOWAIT
END
GO
GRANT EXEC ON [dbo].[proc_name] TO PUBLIC

GO

============================================
```

execute the above sp and use the DataReader to fetch the Output parameter as suggested in the previous answer...

Comment: get the output parameter value in the button click event using DataReader object.... check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432900/reading-output-parameter-without-closing-the-datareader....  based on the value u get, u can do what ever u need...

Comment: This Code show the error

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure Log, Line 11
Must declare the scalar variable "@ErrorSeverity".
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Log, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Log, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: after GO there should not be any statement or line of code. pls remove ========================

Comment: I have done But now its not read the value from table and show the message username or password is invalid :(

Comment: wait .. i will post full answer.

Comment: Hi.. see the answer i just posted.

Answer (score 0):

the following is the complete solution u r looking for,

1. the stored procedure:

   use [YOURDB]

   go

   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'sp_Login')
   BEGIN
   DROP Procedure [dbo].[sp_Login]
   END

   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO

   /*
   File Name : sp_Login.sql
   Description : 
   Author : Vinay.T
   Date :
   */

   CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_Login]
   (
        @Username VarChar(50)
       ,@UPassword varChar(50)
       ,@OutRes    int output

   )
   AS

   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(510) --
           ,@ErrorSeverity INT --16 if business error
   BEGIN

   SET @OutRes = (SELECT count(*) FROM Log_Users WHERE Username = @Username And [Password] = @UPassword)

   END
   GOTO SUCCESS

   SUCCESS:
   RETURN 1
   CRASH:
   RAISERROR (@ErrMsg, @ErrorSeverity, 1) WITH NOWAIT
   END
   GO
   GRANT EXEC ON [dbo].[sp_Login] TO PUBLIC

   GO

2:the button click event code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Login", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPassword", txtPWD.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OutRes", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int output = (int)cmd.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
        if (output == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username Or Password')</script>");
        }
```

let me know this works on not.. ? run the sp against your database..